# Syntax highlight start and end of transparent regions in Vim

Tags: vim, highlight, delimiter, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am writing a syntax highlight file for a language (that didn't already have one) in Vim.

An analogous problem to the one I'm stuck on would be highlighting lists in Python: I want the elements of the list to highlight normally, assuming they are types the language allow to be in such a list, while the list's structure (i.e. `[ , ]` should highlight in its own colour.

Currently I use

```
syn region myList      start='\[' end=']' transparent contains=myList,myDelimiter,myNumber,myString
syn match  myDelimiter ','                contained
```

`myList` contains itself to allow nested lists (hence legal extra `]` end markers) without breaking the region. However, since it is transparent (to allow highlighting of other legal groups (`myNumber` and `myString` in this example)), the `[` start and `]` end brackets remain without highlighting.

The `myDelimiter` group can be considered a workaround to at least highlight the commas (though it's rather pointless without the rest of the structure, i.e. the start `[` and end `]`). Adding the `[` and `]` to the `myDelimiter` pattern like this:

```
syn match  myDelimiter ',\|\[\|]'         contained
```

breaks the `myList` region and makes it activate on unrelated parts of the file (outside of any list, thus breaking other syntax highlights for elements not allowed in a list. I think the problem is that the end isn't considered an end anymore, but a delimiter within a big array spanning to the last array in the file).

[image: Visual explanation of the problem]

I tried adding `matchgroup=myList` to `syn region myList ...` (and ensured it had a corresponding `hi myList ctermfg=red` entry in my colorscheme), but it changed nothing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `:help :syn-region` and check the `matchgroup=` definition. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in the second last paragraph I tried, and unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `matchgroup=myListContainer` to your region definition and after that you can highlight this new group:

```
:hi myListContainer guifg=red
```

You can use for your `matchgroup` any other group name, but I think that it shouldn't be the same as the primary group you're linking to.

Please take a look at the example [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-matchgroup).